# Read a text File which has numeric columns (like -10.0, -9.9, +9.9 etc.) through Apache Flink

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, readfile

I have requirement where I need to read a file which is generated by another application and file has 201 numeric column name like: -10.0, -9.9, -9.8, -9.7 .......0.....+9.7, +9.8, +9.9, +10.0 so total I have 201 columns in the file. I am reading many files through Flink but file has string type column name and I am creating an model Object with the attributes as columns name available in file as below

```
DataSet<Person>> csvInput = env.readCsvFile("file:///path/to/my/textfile")
                         .pojoType(Person.class, "name", "age", "zipcode");
```

above code will ready file and Person object will be populated with the values available in the File.
**I am facing challenge in new requirement where file columns name is numeric and in Java I cannot create a variable with numeric value along with decimal like -10.0 etc.**

like `private String -10.0` not allowed in java

I am seeking for a solution, could any one please help me out here.

Comment: Columns in CSV aren't named. You can give whatever names you want to `.pojoType`

Comment: @Dima its text file and if text file have 4 columns with tab separated then I am reading through Flink and storing them in POJO, I am not sure how to do if file has got columns name as -10.0 as I cannot create POJO with same name and use .pojoType. It will really help if you can write few like code for an example. Appreciated in advance

Comment: Columns don't have names in csv. I have no ida what you are talking about.